# flowplayer won't work with https

Tags: javascript, html, flash, video, https

Flowplayer just won't initialize under https.
Works perfectly with the same code under http.

Funny thing is if I find a website that uses flowplayer and it works there under https and I link it like this:

```
flowplayer("player", 
           "https://3rdparty.com/flowplayer-3.2.7.swf",
            {clip: {url:"https://mysite.com/video.mov"}}
           );
```

it works fine.

But just won't work if I host the flowplayer on my site.
Any ideas?

update: It does work in Firefox, but only when all the resources return 304. If I do Shift+Refresh and every resource gets downloaded (with 200) then it doesn't work.

update: ok, the answer is you can't serve this swf with gzip compression. so if you had something like this:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

change it to:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/css text/javascript
```

done

Comment: What does "initialize under https" mean exactly? Can you show some code?

Comment: "initialize" means the player's swf is downloaded, but the player area is black, e.g. no "play" button. Plus the controls swf is also not downloaded.